# JavaScript + resource bundle

Tags: javascript, resourcebundle

Всем привет пытаюсь сделать на своем приложения смену языка с `jsp` файлом все удалось подключил `bundle` файл и куда надо вставляю это

```
<%=bundle.getString("lang.button." + lang)%>
```

а как быть с js файлом ?

сейчас я так делаю внутри `jsp` создаю

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var closeBtn = '<%=bundle.getString("close.button." + lang)%>';
        var myProfile = '<%=bundle.getString("menu.profile." + lang)%>';
    </script>
```

потом в самом js файле эти переменные подключаю есть альтернативный способ?